# Does the K9 mail client provide a way to get the contents of mail through a broadcast intent?

Tags: android, email

In my application I listen to the email received intent from K9 which works fine but there doesn't seem to contain the actual mail, only the from, to, subject etc. Is there any way to get the actual body of the mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the source code of the **MailWidget** app (http://android.sopht.ca/), I found a way. However, I don't think it is documented:

```
    public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final Uri k9Uri = Uri.parse("content://com.fsck.k9.messageprovider/inbox_messages/");

    static String[] messages_projection = new String[] {
           "_id",
           "date",
           "sender",
           "subject",
           "preview",
           "account",
           "uri",
           "delUri"
         };

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Cursor curSt = mContext.getContentResolver().query(k9Uri, messages_projection, null, null, null);
    curSt.moveToFirst();
        String preview = curSt.getString(curSt.getColumnIndex("preview"));

  }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, but one correction, the column "_ID" is not correct. It must be lower case (aka: "_id") or else it will fail.